# How can I use variable in IN operator in HANA DB?

Tags: sql, database, variables, hana

I'd like to use variable in IN operator. I tried with array but I can't do with it. So I tried with this method:

```
Do BEGIN    

    var = SELECT ELEMENT_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ELEMENT_NAME IN ('1', '2', '3');

    UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET DATE_DATA = ADD_MONTHS( DATE_DATA, 1 )
    WHERE ELEMENT IN (:var);

END
```

But it drops error:  "inconsistent datatype: TABLE type is not comparable with NVARCHAR".

But if I use this, without variable but same query:

```
Do BEGIN    

    UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET DATE_DATA = ADD_MONTHS( DATE_DATA, 1 )
    WHERE ELEMENT IN (SELECT ELEMENT_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ELEMENT_NAME IN ('1', '2', '3'));

END
```

It's perfect. Why run this and the first one isn't? And how can I solve this problem with variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up a comparison of **scalar** values with a table data type.

Table typed variables are only present in SQLScript and the SQLScript compiler does not understand/support automatic conversion of the `:var` table typed variable into a proper sub-query. It's simply not what the table variables are meant to do.

You can easily overcome this issue by doing what you already described, namely using a sub-select:

```
DO 
BEGIN    

var = SELECT 
            ELEMENT_NAME 
      FROM 
           TABLE_NAME 
      WHERE ELEMENT_NAME IN ('1', '2', '3');

    UPDATE TABLE_NAME
           SET DATE_DATA = ADD_MONTHS( DATE_DATA, 1 )
    WHERE 
         ELEMENT IN 
            (select element_name from :var);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  It just doesn't do what you want.  It is equivalent to `=`.  Even if the value has characters such as `,` or `''`; those are just characters in a string.

If you don't have a convenient string splitter function, you can always use string operations:

```
',' || :var || ',' like '%,' || element ',%'
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Basically I'd like to use this variable like an array.
e.g.: 
var = ('1', '2', '3');

UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET DATE_DATA = ADD_MONTHS( DATE_DATA, 1 )
    WHERE ELEMENT IN (:var);
Of course, it doesn't' work, but I hope I find a similar solution. So I tried with a query. But unfortunately, I don't understand your advice how can help me. Can you show me your solution in the example code?